# How to give a link to .pdf file in html for angularjs? ng-src

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf

This is a Product details in my app.js file.

```
{
code:'18471IN-4-CP',
name:'Symbol Bath and Shower Trim',
price:22875.95,
description:'Symbol recessed bath and shower faucet trim with lever handle and diverter button.',
specification:'These are the new specs from json.',
canPurchase:true,
soldOut:false,
images:[
    {
        full:'BathTub.jpg',
        thumb:'Pipe.jpg'
    },
    {
        full:'Shower Trim1.jpg',
        thumb:'Pipe1.jpg'
    }
],
technicalDetail:'6311W-926.pdf',
cadDrawing: 'k_6311w_0.dwg'
},
```

The html code below loads image from img folder as per json var details in app.js

```
<img ng-src="img/{{product.images[0].thumb}}">
```

How to put link which allows to download pdf (6311W-926.pdf which is in pdf folder) or any other file extension?

Something like ---
 ng-src="pdf/{{product.technicalDetail}}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a ng-href="pdf/{{product.technicalDetail}}" target="_blank"> download pdf </a>
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that instead of defining the folder pdf/...  in html file , the path itself can be stored in json i.e. into app.js file?

Comment: @Optimight I think you should have full path of file in json instead of only name. Modify json so it was like this: { technicalDetail: 'pdf/6311W-926.pdf' }

Comment: Since you have angular binding inside the href, you should use ng-href instead of href. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref